# Ad-Hoc Deployment with Xcode 5/iTunes 11

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a strange problem regarding ad-hoc distribution of an app using iTunes 11. 
All settings seems to be OK (provisioning profiles, certificates etc). 
I distribute the app from xcode 5, sign it with adhoc certificate and add it to iTunes.
I install the app from iTunes to my device (iPhone 5, IOS 7.0.2) and everything works fine, but when it's complete, the app remains dark gray/shadowed on the device (no load progress circle in middle). If I tap over the app, it will show "Installing..." forever.

This app is an upgrade from an older version, and the older version can be installed with no problems. The major changes were the conversion from non-arc to arc and the xib replacement with storyboard.

```
Oct  2 16:41:04 Kiphone installd[62] <Notice>: 0x2c3000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/tmp/com.apple.atc.Apps/com……" requested by atc
Oct  2 16:41:04 Kiphone installd[62] <Notice>: 0x2c3000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com…..
Oct  2 16:41:04 Kiphone installd[62] <Notice>: 0x2c3000 install_application: Installing placeholder
Oct  2 16:41:05 Kiphone installd[62] <Notice>: 0x2c3000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.21s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.21s
Oct  2 16:41:11 Kiphone installd[62] <Notice>: 0x241000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com……
B2-4725-AD8B-07C3CCDFB4A9. shouldCommit=1.
Oct  2 16:41:11 Kiphone installd[62] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
Oct  2 16:41:11 Kiphone installd[62] <Error>: 0x241000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012
Oct  2 16:41:14 Kiphone installd[62] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'SSMobile AdHoc CC'
Oct  2 16:41:14 Kiphone installd[62] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'iSS mobile adhoc'
Oct  2 16:41:14 Kiphone installd[62] <Error>: 0x241000 verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for /var/tmp/install_staging.DTmWby/foo_extracted/Payload/ssmD.app/ssmD: 0xe8008016
Oct  2 16:41:14 Kiphone installd[62] <Error>: 0x241000 do_preflight_verification: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.DTmWby/foo_extracted/Payload/ssmD.app
Oct  2 16:41:14 Kiphone installd[62] <Error>: 0x241000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
Oct  2 16:41:15 Kiphone installd[62] <Error>: 0x241000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
```

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, testflightapp.com has a pretty simple deployment procedure and you don't need access to iTunes to do it.

Comment: Happened to me as well...

Comment: Did you run the app first when you installed Xcode5 with ios7 on your device?

Comment: If I run the app directly from xcode on my device, it works fine. I need the ad-hoc deployment to test push notifications.

Comment: Try using [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) to install the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually happens because of some reasons I have found:
- check a 100 times if the build is signed with the correct identity and provisioning profile
- if the device is newly added to the portal and the profile, make sure you have downloaded the new profile and added it to `Xcode`
- try removing the particular profile from the device
- try restarting the device, the computer
- check device logs and especially the `installd` lines for invalid provisioning profile.
- check if the `UDID` of the device is correct in the portal (apps show no more the correct UDID on iOS7)
- once on a fresh new install of iOS I had to wait for 5-10 minutes before it got installed and never happened agian.

Hope one of those suggestions helps.

Comment: Your suggestions are leading somewhere, I added the logs, now I'll mess around with profiles to see where is the problem coming from. Thx.

Comment: Problem solved after removing all provisioning profiles from my device, thx again.